# CPP Primer 5ed. 15.8.1 multiset related

Tags: c++, multiset

While reading Cpp Primer 5ed Chapter15.8.1 (page631), I am confused by the definition of private member - item.

The original goes like:

```
std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Quote>, decltype(compare)*> items{compare};
```

Shouldn't this be like:

```
std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Quote>, decltype(compare)*> items(compare);
```

Here the compare works as the constructor argument.

Comment: It's a shame you skipped chapter 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either works.

Since C++11, it's valid to specify an initializer, including cases that call a constructor, using `{}`.

One difference is that the form using `{}` causes overload resolution to prefer initializer_list constructors, but as long as `compare` can't possibly convert to `std::shared_ptr<Quote>`, that's not an issue here.